# Why use components in Vue.js or React?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So after trying out Vue.js for a little while, it got me thinking...Why do we have to use components?  I don't understand the hype behind them as I can just take a for loop and create a div and get the exact same output as if I were using components.

Vue.js's documentation even says:

> Components are one of the most powerful features of Vue. They help you extend basic HTML elements to encapsulate reusable code.

But again, it seems it can be done with for loops what Components give you.

The same goes for React as well.

If someone can explain it better, I am all ears.

Thanks.

Comment: The key word here is *reusable*.  for-loops generating divs are only reusable via copy/paste (unless you separate them into modules but then you start to re-invent vue or react)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: I mean, the answer to your question is "because they're useful". Each one can have its own, isolated state. The component code can be asynchronously loaded. Events can be easily managed. The code's more readily tested. They can be reused in other parts of the site. The list could go on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on.

Comment: easier to debug/reuse/maintain is a good explanation

Comment: I do not think a for loop is a workable replacement for a [wrapper component](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using components in Vue.js or React is like using a hammer for everything. You can obviously try to nail a screw with a hammer, but not everyone will understand you why, as you can implement every GUI element using `divs` instead of CustomXComponent.

Using components is like using a screwdriver to screw something. Not only their names and shapes are coherent with the thing you want to achieve, but they are faster to do so. Not using it may look like an unprofessional behavior, just not adapting to the right tools for the right things.

If you look into a bunch of `divs`, you have to look down further what they do. If I give you a custom component named `AutoCompleteSearch` you may abstract what it is doing, even though its implemented using plain `divs`.

Comment: Not using components is like forging a new hammer every time you need to nail another screw into place ;)

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason that you would want to use a for loop instead of copy and pasting the same thing N times - the end result to the user is the same, but you'd have code that's significantly more difficult to understand, maintain, and update.

Answer (score 0):

Components are extremely useful because they are meant to be used in a much more complex context than a handful of `div`.

For example, Imagine if you needed to add a calendar to your page along with a big table of data, a large form, dialog boxes and other UI elements. It sure is *doable* without components but it will be much easier to maintain and more readable if you split your code into components.